# jquery .empty() issue: doesn't work in plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I have to write a simple plugin for ajax load.
Page code. (result by razor)

```
<a ajaxLoad="page" href="/Brand">Brand List</a>

<div id="plc1">
  some content
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#plc1").ajaxPageLoad();
        });
</script>
```

In js code.

```
jQuery.fn.ajaxPageLoad =
function () {
    $('a[ajaxLoad*="page"]').click(function () {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
}
```

in page without this implementation empty() work properly but plug-in there is no effect.
what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to empty the `<a>` element? Can you show this in use, and the expected result?

Comment: ok. edited question. after click link, it is load href page. but "some content" stayed in div.

Comment: @patrick: Trying to empty the `div` and replace it with dynamic content when the `a` is clicked, I think.

Comment: @Aureliano: What does "in page without this implementation" mean?

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, the original question didn't have quite so much detail. Just had the plugin, so I couldn't tell if the `<a>` or some other element should be emptied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're hoping `this` will refer to both the `div` and the `a` at the same time.

If I understand your code, you want to empty the element on which your plugin was called when the `<a>` element is clicked.

Currently, in the `click()` handler, `this` is the `<a>` element. You need to retain a reference to the `<div>` against which your plugin was called *outside* the handler.

```
jQuery.fn.ajaxPageLoad = function() {
      // reference the <div> container (or whatever it ends up being)
    var container = this;

    $('a[ajaxLoad*="page"]').click(function() {
        container.empty();           // empty the container
        container.load( this.href ); // load into the container from the href
        return false;                //    of the <a> that was clicked
    });
};

$(function() {
    $("#plc1").ajaxPageLoad();
});
```

Comment: I didn't even notice his use of `this.href`. Well spotted!